# tcp: why only second call to Socket.Receive(byte[]) returns data?

Tags: .net, sockets, tcp

I have typical situation. I need to send "request" to server via tcp and receive response.

```
// socket is connected
socket.Send(CreateRequest());
byte[] br = new byte[VERY_BIG_BUFFER];
int count = socket.Receive(br);   // only 4 bytes received: 15 0 0 0
count = socket.Receive(br);       // here I receive data I actually need
```

However by some reason I have to call `socket.Receive` twice to make everything works.
In extra call I receive just four bytes: 15 0 0 0.

Hardcoding one extra call without understanding why I need it may result in odd problems. Do someone know what's going on and why I need extra call?

Answer (score 2):

TCP is a stream based protocol. It doesn't have a concept of messages. It's just a sequence of bytes.

This means that it can split one `send` call into multiple `receive` calls, and can combine multiple `send` calls into one `receive` call, or a combination thereof.

You need to delimit your messages somehow. A length prefix is a popular choice for binary protocols.

Comment: I see on first Receive I receive that I should receive 15 bytes. On second receive I receive these 15 bytes. But how should I code that? Just droping first Receive is not good right? Should I receive data in loop until I receive the ammount of data from first 4 bytes?

Comment: another question - if tcp is sequence of bytes - why first `socket.Receive` is closed after 4 bytes and why I do not need to reconnect to call second `socket.Receive`

Comment: "Should I receive data in loop until I receive the amount of data from first 4 bytes" yes that's the way to go. | In TCP `receive` can return fewer bytes than requested whenever it feels like it. For example because that many bytes have already arrived, and the rest is still in transit. Then you can call it again to receive more. `receive` returning `0` indicates the end of the stream.