# Asynchronous Socket doesn't work

Tags: c#, http, sockets, networking, tcp

I am building an custom HTTP-Request class with Sockets. My code is based on the MSDN-Guid for asynchronous Sockets, but unfourtunately it doesn't work. The Request works well, but I don't receive complete response. Can maybe someone help me with this problem?
Here is my code:

```
private void BeginConnect()
{
    //Connect To Server
    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    socket.BeginConnect(this.ResolveUrl(_requestUri), new AsyncCallback(this.ConnectCallback), socket);
}
private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    //Get Socket
    Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

    //Complete Connection
    socket.EndConnect(ar);

    //Send HTTP Request
    byte[] requestBytes = this.CreateRequest();
    socket.BeginSend(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(this.SendCallback), socket);
}
private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    //Get Socket
    Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

    //Complete Sending
    socket.EndSend(ar);

    // Create the state object.
    StateObject state = new StateObject();
    state.WorkSocket = socket;

    //Recieve Response
    socket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(this.ReceiveCallback), state);
}
private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    //Get StateObject
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket socket = state.WorkSocket;

    //Complete Receiving
    int bytesRead = socket.EndReceive(ar);
    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        //Save Already Received Data
        state.ResponseBuilder.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, bytesRead));

        //Get Rest Of The Data.
        socket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(this.ReceiveCallback), state);
    }
    else
    {
        if (state.ResponseBuilder.Length > 1)
        {
            //Shutdown Socket
            socket.BeginDisconnect(false, new AsyncCallback(this.DisconnectCallback), state);

            //Invoke Callback
            SocketResponse resp = new SocketResponse(state.ResponseBuilder.ToString(), HttpStatusCode.Accepted); //TODO
            _callback.Invoke(resp);
        }
    }
}
private void DisconnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    //Get Socket
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket socket = state.WorkSocket;

    //Shutdown Socket
    socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    socket.Close();
}
```

Comment: I guess it's the usual TCP problem. i.e. it TCP is a stream and not a message based protocol, and thus a send call can be split into multiple receive calls. A few potential duplicates [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5528234/445517) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8575659/445517) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9895132/445517)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCP connections are stream based. The quantity of data you can read each time involves an element of randomness and you need to loop over the read until you have the whole message.

Implementing sockets is an error prone exercise if you have no previous networking experience. Having said that all of these problems have been solved in the open source network communication library [networkComms.net](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net). If you follow the very basic, 11 line, example, [here](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net/src/6744de0b61f3/ExamplesConsole/BasicSend.cs), all the way down the call tree you will see how to implement async sockets correctly.

Comment: Two significant downsides IMO 1) I can't find a protocol spec 2) GPL