# Multi send() or receive() in TCP

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I would like to do some client and server to sharing files each other. I have an issue, because TCP "messages" are merged, despite I set how many bytes I would like to send and how many receive.

I had a look on it, and the problem occurs when in the first "message" I send a filename and after that (in new Send()) I send the file content, for example.

I fixed it by sending a feedback message after each receive packet currently.

Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data loss TCP IP C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528234/data-loss-tcp-ip-c-sharp)

Comment: More duplicates: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8575659/445517) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9895132/445517)

Comment: I did something like

        `string msg = "test";

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        byte[] prefix = BitConverter.GetBytes(msg.Length);
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);

        Array.Copy(prefix, 0, buf, 0, prefix.Length);
        Array.Copy(data, 0, buf, prefix.Length, data.Length);

        socket.Send(buf);`

but I don't know how to receive the message now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a length prefix to each message. And then read in a loop until you receive as many bytes as you want.